# What function would give a TRUE value if either of two conditions are met?

Tags: formulas, conditional-formatting

I want conditional formatting to change the cell color of a selected range when the text is exactly one of two possibilities. I have a function which concatenates three cells of text together, and this function is applied to a column. When a root word is typed in the vertical column (e.g. ma and pa in picture), a defined affix and auxiliary are concatenated together in a specified order. This has the side effect of creating a column of auxiliary-affix combinations which I do not want.

One solution is to use conditional formatting to change the text and cell color to white. Another solution would be editing the formula somehow to give a blank result if no root word is typed. I'm not too familiar with spreadsheet formula syntax, and that's why I am here.

What is the best way to 'blur out' the text which does not contain the root word? I want to apply this solution to hundreds of cells, so I need an efficient solution. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Here is my concatenation formula for one cell:

```
=Ifs(
    $B$9 & $B$10="Pre-verb Auxiliary"&"Prefixes", $C$9 & $C$10 & B12,
    $B$9 & $B$10="Post-verb Auxiliary"&"Prefixes", $C$10 & B12 & $C$9,
    $B$9 & $B$10="Pre-verb Auxiliary"&"Suffixes", $C$9 & B12 & $C$10,
    $B$9 & $B$10="Post-verb Auxiliary"&"Suffixes", B12 & $C$10 & $C$9
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your cells based on your picture. You can try something like this:

```
=NOT(REGEXMATCH(B6:B,JOIN("|",FILTER($A$6:$A,$A$6:$A <> ""))))
```

But I think that your combination formula may be perfected in order not to create empty those values. If you share it, we could be able to help